# Efficiency of data storage in terms of cache-locality

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, garbage-collection

I want to make a data storage that looks like this:

1. I have an array of structures, that are some kind of smart pointers. Each pointer contain information about displacement of an object in the stack-array (the storage that contain all objects), size of an object, and number of holders:

```
struct ObjPtr {
    int disp;  // displacement
    int size;  // size of an object
    int count; // number of holders
}

// somewhere in code...
// Assume I can create only 1024 objects just for example.
ObjPtr* smart_pointers = (ObjPtr*)calloc(1024, sizeof(ObjPtr));
```

2. I have a stack-array that contains all objects:

```
// Assume 64 MB is enough
char* obj_stack = (char*)calloc(64 * 1024 * 1024, sizeof(char))
int stack_top; // displacement of the top of the obj_stack
```

It's just a plain array of bytes. Each object is allocated at the top of stack and then we do `stack_top += sizeof(allocated_type)`. If there is not enough memory we compress the `obj_stack`.
**Totally everywhere** in my program i what to use **the index** of `ObjPtr` in `smart_pointers` array instead of pointers:

```
// Access an object:
SomeObject* some_object = (SomeObject*)(obj_stack + pointers[objPointer_index].disp)
```

Notice that I'm abstracting from the questions like how to compress the stack, object alignment on the stack, how to store indices of freed smart-pointers, atomicity of counter increment/decrement, cyclic references, memory overhead of smart pointers, performance overhead during accessing an object etc.

**The question which I afraid of is:**
As I understand how virtual memory works, processor does not retrieve several words from memory but tries to predict further memory accesses and load a little bit more and place it to the cache. It's called the **principle of locality**. I guess a typical allocator provided by compiler is trying to preserve locality. This storage is designed such way that references and objects are stored on different pages. This violate principle of locality. But it is a little problem. The big problem is that, in long term, after several compressions, it's possible that objects (that work together, refer each other) are spread across the whole stack-array. So I guess the processor will crazily jump from one page to another. It's like vector vs. linked list cache misses. How do you think is my assumption correct? Should I care of locality and fragmentation?

Comment: Depends on the architecture or smartness of the processor, and of course, how much cache memory is allocated to data.

Comment: *but retrieve the whole page (4 KB) and place it to the cache*. That's not typically how things work. The are many different arrangements of memory caches but at a high level they work on much smaller "cache lines/blocks". Each cache line is typically in the order of 10 of bytes and certainly not kilobytes. Note: that's a very generalised description.

Comment: Whether or not a cache completely reloads has some decision attributes.  Sometimes, reloading a *cache-line* is more efficient that loading the entire cache.  There are a lot of dependencies here.  For example, is the processor locking the data bus for a long time to reload entire cache, more efficient than locking the data bus for smaller periods (so other data bus hardware can use it).

Comment: The cache granularity is a _cache line_ which is typically 64 bytes and has nothing to do with virtual memory and page size.